# Adding ERP specific tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

I have been seeing some ERP specific questions on the site, which may require a bit of specific domain knowledge such as this one: [Slow without recompile](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156152/slow-without-recompile/156579) or this one: [SQL perf issue - configure server correctly first or troubleshoot issues one by one?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141247/sql-perf-issue-configure-server-correctly-first-or-troubleshoot-issues-one-by/141276) or even some asked by me [sp_cursoropen and parallelism](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106454/sp-cursoropen-and-parallelism) or [Verifying connection pooling server side with CONTEXT_INFO on](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101286/verifying-connection-pooling-server-side-with-context-info-on)

Mentioning the fact that these were related to Dynamics AX would imply some of the specifics and restrictions of said ERP system.

I noticed there are tags for some of the SAP products, but none for the Dynamics line (just like there are none for example for peoplesoft or whatever).

Would it make sense to have a tag for some ERP vendor systems just so some people could

A) indicate they are using a system with limited features or try to appeal to users experienced in the said system
   B) provide the possibility for people like me to monitor a queue

I realize this may be a path leading to endless vendor specific tags, but I do also think it may be a way for so-called specialists to keep an eye out for questions within their domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some contemplating and discussion back and forth I think the most appropriate tag would be `microsoft-dynamics` since there are multiple products in the product line, but Microsoft is in the process  of merging them and calling them Dynamics 365.

The tag `dynamics` could possibly be applied to a lot of questions completely unrelated to the product line.

`dynamics-365` would be too limiting to include only the, recently released, current version and exclude the versions most in use at the moment and creating `dynamics-ax` for example is getting outdated as we speak by the Microsoft marketing department. Furthermore I don't think Microsoft has really decided on their upcoming naming strategy so we could update our tags when they make up their minds.

Unfortunately I already tagged some questions and created a tag wiki for `dynamics` so I would probably need some help by overworked internet volunteers to fix it.

Comment: [tag:microsoft-dynamics] created and [tag:dynamics] merged into it.